# Two forms (1 ajax and 1 regular post) with one Model on same razor page

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have a page that looks up vehicle information based on VIN number then adds it to a grid.  The lookup is on a Modal popup and is simple ajax call that loads data into a ViewComponent.

The code in the ViewComponent just displays the Year, Make, Model, etc... and it is working correctly.

Now the issue...  The modal is still open and shows all the vehicle data in the Viewcomponent. There is a form with some additional info that is needed.  Now I need to submit this form which should have all CurrentVehicleInfo values plus the additional info that are just assigned to additional properties in the CurrentVehicleInfo class.
This submit should close the modal and add the vehicle to a grid on the main page.

When I get to Add the vehicle (OnPostAddVehicle function) CurrentVehicleInfo has all the default values and not the values that I looked up.

What I think is the problem is that I am not keeping the value of CurrentVehcileInfo when I do the Ajax call. And since it is a separate form I cannot store them in a hidden field.  How do I accomplish this.

Sample Code BElow

This is the VinLookup Form (Regular form with Ajax)

```
<form method="post"
                  role="form"
                  asp-antiforgery="true"
                  data-ajax="true"
                  data-ajax-method="post"
                  data-ajax-url="?handler=ValidateVin"
                  data-ajax-update="#VehicleInfoContainer"
                  data-ajax-mode="replace"
                  data-ajax-loading="#spinner"
                  data-ajax-failure="onFailed">
                <div class="row mt-4">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">Vin Number</h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="form-group text-center">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <label asp-for="VinNumber"></label>: <input asp-for="VinNumber" class="form-control inputStandard mr-3" />
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-primary">
                                            <span id="spinner" style="display:none;" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-light" role="status"></span>
                                            Validate Vin
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Properties

```
    [BindProperty]
    public Vehicle CurrentVehicleInfo { get; set; } = new Vehicle();
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Vehicle> CurrentVehicles { get; set; } = new List<Vehicle>();
```

This is the Action that gets vin info (The CurrentVehcicleInfo is populated in ValidateVin)

```
        public IActionResult OnPostValidateVinAsync(string vinNumber)
    {
        ValidateVin();
        return ViewComponent("VehicleInformation", CurrentVehicleInfo);
    }
```

The additional form is

```
                <form method="post" asp-page-handler="AddVehicle">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="CurrentVehicleInfo.Year" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="CurrentVehicleInfo.Make" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="CurrentVehicleInfo.Model" />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Vehicle to Booking</button>
                </form>
```

Which calls this action

```
        public IActionResult OnPostAddVehicle()
    {
        var test = CurrentVehicleInfo;
        return Page();
    }
```

Comment: First, you can use the network tab in the browser's developer tools to confirm what values (if any) are being posted, and second, you can use JavaScript to set values in hidden fields. JS has access to anything in the DOM, including form fields in all forms.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help.  I thought I there was something I was missing to do this without javascript.  I ended up creating hidden fields on both forms and in the OnSuccess for the ajax call I copied the data from one to the other.